# "The object invoked has disconnected from its clients."

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a button that prompts for input and creates a new tab.  The first run it works great, but subsequent runs throw this error:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
Sub btnAddProject()
    Dim template As Worksheet
    Dim newSheet As Worksheet
    Dim newName As String


    newName = Application.InputBox("Enter Project Name")        'get name
    Worksheets("Template").Visible = True                       'Unhide template
    Set template = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Template")            'identify template
    template.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)                   'create copy
    Set newSheet = ActiveSheet                                  'identify new sheet
    newSheet.Name = newName                                     'rename sheet
    'deleteNames (newSheet.Name)                                'delete copied named ranges with worksheet scope
    newSheet.Range("D2").Value = newName                        'Change header on new sheet
    Worksheets("Template").Visible = False                      'Hide template
    Worksheets("Consolidated Grid").Activate                    'switch back to dashboard
    updateProjectIndex (newName)
End Sub
```

The error is thrown on `newSheet.Name = newName` and it leaves me with a sheet named "Template (2)"

What is causing this?

In case it's relevant, here is the `updateProjectIndex` sub which basically just adds a new line to the list of projects (in two places):

```
Sub updateProjectIndex(newName)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Dashboard").Select

    ActiveSheet.Rows(12).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

    ActiveSheet.Range("B13").Value = newName


    Sheets("Consolidated Grid").Select

    ActiveSheet.Columns("F:F").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlRight

    ActiveSheet.Range("G1").Value = newName


    Sheets("Dashboard").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("B13").Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: hmmm, that's interesting.  I'll keep poking it with a stick, thanks for looking.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine for me although I had to remove the additional sub calls (so I removed `updateProjectIndex(newName)` AND `Worksheets("Consolidated Grid").Activate`

To debug, try this code in a new Excel on your PC to see if the issue is workbook related to that workbook or Excel

The issue is in code in an event

Try commenting out those 2 lines of code and see if the issue persists or not. If no issue, uncomment one at a time until you see the bug, and eliminate that way.

I'd recommend you do this with a copy of your file so you can break it as much as you like!

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out, though I'm not sure why.  I had the following code in my `Workbook_Open` sub:

```
   Worksheets("Dashboard").Activate
    If InStr(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path, "sharepoint.com") Then
        Range("1:1").Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True

    Else
        Range("1:1").Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
```

The intent was to make sure people knew they were opening an offline version.  I'm assuming the conflict was with the `Worksheets.Activate` here?  Maybe someone can explain.

Either way, removing this seems to have fixed the problem 100%.

Update: Replaced all the code but the `.Activate` and it is still working.  I'm guessing activating a workbook from its own Workbook_Open routine was causing some sort of loop?

Comment: Just avoid using `.Activate` all together..

Comment: Is `.select` preferred?  Does it accomplish the same thing? (ie "switch to")

Comment: Be sure to avoid things like `.Select` - it just slows the code down by needing to fiddle with the spreadsheet while doing everything else behind the scenes. There's a good question on StackOverflow addressing this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros .

Comment: If you need to "switch to" then define some variables for each object and just use the variables instead of activating them. Your Else statement could simply be `Range("1:1").entirerow.hidden = false`

Comment: That doesn't explain how to switch to another tab...

Comment: Tabs are sheets, just use the sheet object, range object etc. I can't explain it all in comments but [here is an example](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/100878/75587) of some of the stuff I'm talking about by a user schooling me on it.

Comment: I pinged you, but [we can continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38135/discussion-on-question-1062608)

Comment: Those are all modifying things. I literally want to change to another sheet/tab.  I have a button that says "Return to dashboard".  How do I switch to the dashboard sheet?

Comment: To return to dashboard yes, that would be .activate